# how test for negative return from JSON search

Tags: jquery, json

I'm building a function that searches a json object and pulls up all the schools within a certain zipcode. I have a script that works when the search comes up positive, but I'm having trouble testing for the negative result condition so I can put up a "No school found" message. I've stripped down to just the bit that looks for a negative result:

```
       $('#search').keyup(function(){
  if ($(this).val().length > 4) {
       $('#results').css({ "display": 'block'});
       var searchField = $('#search').val();
      var regex = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
        $.getJSON('schools.json', function(data) {
          $.each(data, function(key, val){
            if ((val.zip.search(regex) == -1) ) {
                var statusmsg2 = "No school found for that zip code. Please check it and try again.";
                $('#results').html(statusmsg2);
          });   /* End 'if search length < 1' */
        });  /* End 'getJSON' */
         }  /* End 'if' */
   }); // end keyup function
```

The basic problem is I don't know how to write the conditional. What do I test for instead of this:

```
if ((val.zip.search(regex) == -1) )
```

Or is there a different approach entirely?

Comment: what is the result that is returned from the server?

Comment: Do you control the server script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the error message as the default message, then overwrite it if a match is found.

It would have been more helpful if you actually included the code that finds matches, but something like this

```
$('#search').keyup(function () {
    if ($(this).val().length > 4) {
        var searchField = $('#search').val();
        var regex = new RegExp(searchField, "i");

        $('#results').css("display", 'block');

        $.getJSON('schools.json', function (data) {
            var statusmsg = "No school found for that zip code. Please check it and try again.";

            $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                if (val.zip.search(regex) != -1) {
                    statusmsg = val.message; // or whatever
                    return false;
                });
            });

            $('#results').html(statusmsg);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks adeneo! I had originally tried that logic but it wasn't working due to a fairly trivial error that made me think something more fundamental was wrong. Your version TOTALLY helped me solve it. This now works!